# Logic to write the first 10 numbers without using any for loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am fresher and just gave my first interview on friday.

In a machine test they ask me to write a program to add first ten numbers i.e 1-10 without using any for loop. I tried it alot but can not find the solution. How can we write a program logic to get the sum of first 10 natural numbers without using for loop.

Comment: use a recursive function.

Comment: oh yes I forgot that damn. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they asked you not to use for loop , then you could have use while or do while.
There is another way to do it if you dont want to use any knd of loop.You can use the formula
**1+2+3+.........+(n-1)+n=(n*(n+1))/2** .

you had to add first 10 numbers so you could have use it like

**(10*(10+1))/2.**

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}",(10*(10+1))/2);
```

You can make it more general by asking the user the value of n etc.I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sir and Thanks alot to the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 2):

The natural numbers are a special case of an [arithmetic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series). The sum of *any* arithmetic series can be computed with a simple formula, without requiring a loop.

S = (n / 2) * (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>)

Personally, I think it would kind of unfair for an interviewer to expect you to just remember this formula off the top of your head. However, you probably would impress an interviewer a great deal by working through the series and figuring out the formula yourself!

Comment: Yes Sir you are right ,I even never ever read this formula, but I could have do it using reccurssion. my bad luck but thanks all for you guys for this enormous support .You guys are genious.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you could just use simple mathematics.

```
x = firstnaturalnumber;
```

You want to have:

```
(x + 0) + (x + 1) + (x + 2) ... (x + 9)
```

Natural numbers are whole integers, which makes this mathematically sound.  The final equation is:

```
sum = 10x + 45
```

Comment: Thanks Sir and Thanks alot to the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

if they specified not to use 'for' loop then there are other loops available such as do-while or while. Recursive function is also a good choice.

Actually, they have already specified the numbers to be added. So, instead of being a smart arse, use '+' to add them directly. Yeah I one it is dumb answer but it is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", SumRecursive(1,10));
}

static int SumRecursive(int min, int max) {
    return _SumRecursive(min, max);
}


static int _SumRecursive(int min, int val) {
    if (val == min)
        return val;
    return val + _SumRecursive(min, val - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a recursive method , and there is no for loop either

```
public int AddDown(int i)
{
    return i += (i >= 1 ? AddDown(--i) : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

x= 1 + 2 + 3+.....+n-2 +n-1+n

x =n +n-1+ n-2+ ....3+2 +1        just reversing

sum up both sides

2x= (n+1) +(n+1) +(n+1)+ .....+(n+1)     ///n times

2x= n(n+1)

x= n(n+1)/2

so in your case  x= 10(10+1)/2 = 55